# How to set or change notification buttons position

Tags: android, xamarin, android-notifications

Can not find any information about buttons positioning. I have discovered that different devices show buttons in different (left\center\right)

I can provide some code from my Xamarin project but Kotlin\Java code should be almost the same

```js
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, ChannelId)
                                      .SetSmallIcon(ApplicationContext.ApplicationInfo.Icon)
                                      .SetContentTitle("title")
                                      .SetContentText("message")
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true) 
                                      .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(message))
                                      .SetColor(Resource.Color.orange)
                                      .SetContentIntent(contentIntent);

var buttonIntent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(NotificationReceiver));
buttonIntent.PutExtra(NotificationConstants.SelectedActionKey, selectedAction);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(ApplicationContext, requestCode, buttonIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
notificationBuilder.AddAction(0, "cool button", pendingIntent),
```

Comment: What kind of button you are referring to ?

Comment: PendingIntent, I have updated the code

Comment: For that, I think you need to use custom view for notification.

Comment: It would be rather annoying to create RemoteView (custom) for such a small feature like action button alignment..

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to pick how the default actions are displayed. But you can instead custom view.

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews("com.companyname.NotificationChannelsDemo", Resource.Layout.layout1);

var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID2)                                                       
                          .SetCustomContentView(remoteViews).
.........
```

`com.companyname.NotificationChannelsDemo` is your package name.

`Resource.Layout.layout1` is the layout of your custom view. You could set the button position in this layout.